# PHP 5 jsoon_encode проблема с кирилицей режет код

Tags: php, json, кириллица, json-encode

В php собираются данные и затем выводятся в json_encode в json строку, но вот беда он режет код после большого количества json символов кириллицы

По моим подсчетам лажа происходит после 5900 символов utf-8 в строке `\u043c\u0438\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0441\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0441\u0442\**u0432\…**`

То есть большой json в кириллице передать не могу как обойти эту проблему!!

```
{"orders":[{"externalOrderId":11,"externalCustomerId":0,"status":"DELIVERED","date":"2017-08-13T15:43:01+05:00","email":"","phone":"+998945656546","firstName":"Anton","lastName":"Shumeyko","currency":"USD","restoreUrl":"fito.com\/admin\/index.php?route=sale\/order\/info&order_id=11","statusDescription":"Pending","storeId":"fito.com\/","paymentMethod":"\u041e\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043f\u0440\u0438 \u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0435","deliveryAddress":"\u0413\u0434\u0435-\u0442\u043e \u0432 \u0422\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0435","items":[{"externalItemId":"50","name":"\u041a\u0440\u0435\u043c \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0431\u0435\u0437\u043e\u043f\u0430\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0437\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0430 \u0422\u041c \u0411\u0438\u043e\u043a\u043e\u043d SPF-30 90\u043c\u043b","category":"Cameras","quantity":1,"cost":54,"url":"fito.com\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=50","imageUrl":"fito.com\/\/image\/catalog\/krem-detckii-dlya-bezopacnogo-zagara-tm-biokon-spf-30-90ml-10064-300x300.jpg","description":"&lt;h2 style=&quot;font-family: &amp;quot;Open Sans&amp;quot;, sans-serif; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 0px; font-size: 24px;&quot;&gt;\u041a\u0440\u0435\u043c \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0431\u0435\u0437\u043e\u043f\u0430\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0437\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0430 \u0422\u041c \u0411\u0438\u043e\u043a\u043e\u043d SPF-30 90\u043c\u043b.&lt;\/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;\u0421\u043f\u0435\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e \u0441\u043e\u0437\u0434\u0430\u043d \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0437\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u044b \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u043a\u043e\u0436\u0438 \u043e\u0442 \u0443\u043b\u044c\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0444\u0438\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u043b\u0443\u0447\u0435\u0439 UVB \u0438 UVA \u043f\u0440\u0438 \u043b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0439 \u0441\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438. \u0421\u043f\u043e\u0441\u043e\u0431\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0443\u0435\u0442 \u043f\u043e\u044f\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044e \u0440\u043e\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0437\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0430 \u0431\u0435\u0437 \u0440\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0430 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0438\u044f \u0441\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043e\u0436\u043e\u0433\u0430.&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;em&gt;\u041f\u0440\u0438 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0438 \u0438 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u043f\u0435\u0447\u0430\u0442\u043a\u0435 \u043c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043b\u0430 \u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0441\u0441\u044b\u043b\u043a\u0430 \u043d\u0430 fito.com \u043e\u0431\u044f\u0437\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430.&lt;\/em&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;"},{"externalItemId":"51","name":"\u0414\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0437\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043a\u0440\u0435\u043c-\u0431\u0430\u043b\u044c\u0437\u0430\u043c \u0441 \u043e\u043b\u0438\u0432\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044b\u043c \u043c\u0430\u0441\u043b\u043e\u043c \u0438 \u044d\u043a\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043e\u043c \u0440\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0438 75\u043c\u043b","category":"Cameras","quantity":1,"cost":22,"url":"fito.com\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=51","imageUrl":"fito.com\/\/image\/catalog\/detckii-zashitnii-krem-bal-zam-c-olivkovim-maclom-i-iekctraktom-romashki-75ml-9865-300x300.jpg","description":"&lt;div style=&quot;color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;\u041e\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0431\u043b\u0435\u043c\u043e\u0439, \u0441 \u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0439 \u0412\u044b \u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u0441\u0442\u043e\u043b\u043a\u043d\u0443\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u043f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0431\u044b\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0441 \u0440\u0435\u0431\u0451\u043d\u043a\u043e\u043c \u043d\u0430 \u043c\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0437\u0435, \u044f\u0432\u043b\u044f\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0441\u0443\u0445\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c \u0438 \u0448\u0435\u043b\u0443\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043a\u043e\u0436\u0438. \u0412 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u043e\u043c \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435, \u0432\u0441\u0451, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0412\u0430\u043c \u043d\u0435\u043e\u0431\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043c\u043e - \u044d\u0442\u043e \u043c\u044f\u0433\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0437\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u043a\u0440\u0435\u043c \u043e\u0442 \u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0438 \u00ab\u042d\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0441\u0438\u0440\u00bb, \u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u044b\u0439 \u0437\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u0438\u0442 \u043a\u043e\u0436\u0443 \u0412\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0433\u043e \u0440\u0435\u0431\u0451\u043d\u043a\u0430 \u043e\u0442 \u043b\u044e\u0431\u044b\u0445 \u043a\u0430\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0437\u043e\u0432 \u043f\u043e\u0433\u043e\u0434\u044b. \u0414\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043a\u0440\u0435\u043c \u0441\u043f\u0435\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430\u043d \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0437\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u044b \u0447\u0443\u0432\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u043a\u043e\u0436\u0438 \u0437\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0439 \u043e\u0442 \u0445\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0434\u0430, \u0432\u0435\u0442\u0440\u0430 \u0438 \u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043c\u0438\u043d\u043e\u0437\u0430. \u0411\u043b\u0430\u0433\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0440\u044f \u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u044b\u043c \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0434\u043d\u044b\u043c \u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u043e\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043c, \u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u044b\u0435 \u0441\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0430\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0432 \u043a\u0440\u0435\u043c\u0435, \u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0433\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u044d\u0444\u0444\u0435\u043a\u0442 \u0441\u043c\u044f\u0433\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f, \u0437\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u044b \u0438 \u0443\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043a\u043e\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043d\u0435\u0436\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u043a\u043e\u0436\u0438. \u0410 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0436\u0435 \u0443\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0433\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u0435\u0435 \u043e\u0442 \u0432\u043e\u0437\u043d\u0438\u043a\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043c\u0438\u043a\u0440\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0449\u0438\u043d \u0438 \u0448\u0435\u043b\u0443\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f, \u0432\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0438\u0432\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u044d\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c.&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/div&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;&quot;&gt;\u0421\u0432\u043e\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0430:&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;\u0411\u043b\u0430\u0433\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0440\u044f \u043c\u0430\u0441\u043b\u0443 \u0436\u043e\u0436\u043e\u0431\u0430 \u043d\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u0436\u0435 \u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0443\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0437\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043a\u0430, \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u044f\u044e\u0449\u0430\u044f \u0435\u0435 \u043e\u0442 \u043c\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0437\u0430, \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u0442\u0432\u0440\u0430\u0449\u0430\u044e\u0449\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0438 \u0448\u0435\u043b\u0443\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435.&lt;\/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;\u042d\u043a\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442 \u0440\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0438 \u043e\u043a\u0430\u0437\u044b\u0432\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0441\u043f\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0435, \u0443\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0438\u0432\u0430\u044e\u0449\u0435\u0435 \u0438 \u0430\u043d\u0442\u0438\u0431\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0434\u0435\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0438\u0435.&lt;\/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;\u041c\u0430\u0441\u043b\u043e \u043e\u0431\u043b\u0435\u043f\u0438\u0445\u0438, \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435\u043c\u043e\u0435 \u0438\u0437 \u043f\u043b\u043e\u0434\u043e\u0432, \u043e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u044d\u043f\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u0438\u0440\u0443\u044e\u0449\u0438\u043c\u0438, \u0433\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0443\u043b\u0438\u0440\u0443\u044e\u0449\u0438\u043c\u0438 \u0438 \u0431\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0443\u0442\u043e\u043b\u044f\u044e\u0449\u0438\u043c\u0438 \u0441\u0432\u043e\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0430\u043c\u0438. \u041e\u0431\u043b\u0435\u043f\u0438\u0445\u0430 - \u043f\u0440\u0435\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043c\u0438\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0441\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0441\u0442\u0432\…
```

Вот кстати с той же оперы валидный  json (меньше кирилицы)
`{"orders":[{"externalOrderId":12,"externalCustomerId":0,"status":"DELIVERED","date":"2017-08-13T17:27:49+05:00","email":"","phone":"56456546","firstName":"Anton","lastName":"Shum","currency":"USD","restoreUrl":"fito.com\/admin\/index.php?route=sale\/order\/info&order_id=12","statusDescription":"Pending","storeId":"fito.com\/","paymentMethod":"\u041e\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043f\u0440\u0438 \u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0435","deliveryAddress":"\u0413\u0434\u0435-\u0442\u043e \u0432 \u0422\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0435","items":[{"externalItemId":"50","name":"\u041a\u0440\u0435\u043c \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0431\u0435\u0437\u043e\u043f\u0430\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0437\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0430 \u0422\u041c \u0411\u0438\u043e\u043a\u043e\u043d SPF-30 90\u043c\u043b","category":"Cameras","quantity":1,"cost":54,"url":"fito.com\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=50","imageUrl":"fito.com\/\/image\/catalog\/krem-detckii-dlya-bezopacnogo-zagara-tm-biokon-spf-30-90ml-10064-300x300.jpg","description":"&lt;h2 style=&quot;font-family: &amp;quot;Open Sans&amp;quot;, sans-serif; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 0px; font-size: 24px;&quot;&gt;\u041a\u0440\u0435\u043c \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0431\u0435\u0437\u043e\u043f\u0430\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0437\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0430 \u0422\u041c \u0411\u0438\u043e\u043a\u043e\u043d SPF-30 90\u043c\u043b.&lt;\/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;\u0421\u043f\u0435\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e \u0441\u043e\u0437\u0434\u0430\u043d \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0437\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u044b \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u043a\u043e\u0436\u0438 \u043e\u0442 \u0443\u043b\u044c\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0444\u0438\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u043b\u0443\u0447\u0435\u0439 UVB \u0438 UVA \u043f\u0440\u0438 \u043b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0439 \u0441\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438. \u0421\u043f\u043e\u0441\u043e\u0431\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0443\u0435\u0442 \u043f\u043e\u044f\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044e \u0440\u043e\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0437\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0430 \u0431\u0435\u0437 \u0440\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0430 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0438\u044f \u0441\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043e\u0436\u043e\u0433\u0430.&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(95, 101, 105); font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;em&gt;\u041f\u0440\u0438 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0438 \u0438 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u043f\u0435\u0447\u0430\u0442\u043a\u0435 \u043c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043b\u0430 \u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0441\u0441\u044b\u043b\u043a\u0430 \u043d\u0430 fito.com \u043e\u0431\u044f\u0437\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430.&lt;\/em&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;"},{"externalItemId":"30","name":"Canon EOS 5D","category":"Desktops","quantity":1,"cost":80,"url":"fito.com\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=30","imageUrl":"fito.com\/\/image\/catalog\/demo\/canon_eos_5d_1.jpg","description":"&lt;p&gt;\r\n\tCanon's press material for the EOS 5D states that it 'defines (a) new D-SLR category', while we're not typically too concerned with marketing talk this particular statement is clearly pretty accurate. The EOS 5D is unlike any previous digital SLR in that it combines a full-frame (35 mm sized) high resolution sensor (12.8 megapixels) with a relatively compact body (slightly larger than the EOS 20D, although in your hand it feels noticeably 'chunkier'). The EOS 5D is aimed to slot in between the EOS 20D and the EOS-1D professional digital SLR's, an important difference when compared to the latter is that the EOS 5D doesn't have any environmental seals. While Canon don't specifically refer to the EOS 5D as a 'professional' digital SLR it will have obvious appeal to professionals who want a high quality digital SLR in a body lighter than the EOS-1D. It will also no doubt appeal to current EOS 20D owners (although lets hope they've not bought too many EF-S lenses...) \u00e4\u00eb&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n"}],"deliveryMethod":"\u0414\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0430 \u043f\u043e \u0433\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0443  (\u0412\u0435\u0441: 0.00kg)","shipping":"11.6000","totalCost":"145.6000"}]}`

Comment: три точки в конце и json ломается вывожу через echo

Comment: Пропробуйте сперва узнать в чем именно проблема: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: Manitikyl, изучил ее у меня проблема в другом когда текст в description небольшой все работает а когда большой все падает

Comment: какую ошибку-то выдает json_last_error_msg?